# No Keyboard input if QLineEdit on frameless popup window

Tags: qt

When a parent widget is defined with:

```
setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::Popup);
```

Any edit box widget placed on top of it will not receive keyboard input. Mouse will work, right click, context menu, paste will work -- but not direct keyboard input. Any ideas why and how it can be fixed?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem, on Windows 7, with Qt Creator 2.3.1 and Qt 4.7.4. All I have is a QMainWindow, with one widget which is a QLineEdit - and I called your setWindowFlags(line) on the QMainWindow. It worked fine - I was able to type text, no problem.

Comment: The container window on my application is not the main window. Maybe that makes the difference. One person on another forum suggested he had a similar problem which was resolved when he activated the container window. Will give it a try and post my results here.

Comment: I have the same problem. I have a simple class derived from QDialog and in the constructor I set the Qt::WindowFlags to Qt::Popup. It seems that this is a Qt bug. Windows 7, Qt 4.8 => works fine. Windows 7, Qt 5.4 => does not work. Windows 8, Qt 5.4 => does not work. However if I setup a breakpoint and pause the execution for a while (in the showEvent( QShowEvent* ) ) and then continue the execution I can use that QLineEdit in the desired way.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned previously in a comment I had the same problem but now it is fixed with the following code:

```
// virtual override
void MyDialog::showEvent( QShowEvent* aShowEvent )
{
    QDialog::showEvent( aShowEvent );
    activateWindow();
}
```

After I added the activateWindow() function call I could use QLineEdit on my popup dialog.

I use Visual Studio 2013 and Qt 5.4.1 on Windows 8.1.

Comment: Thanks!!! It also work for widget in a menu action. Without this, it could not activate the input method.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try [activating the window](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#activateWindow) and/or [setting widget focus](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#setFocus)?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "qfindedit.h"

QFindEdit::QFindEdit(QWidget *parent)
: QLineEdit(parent)
, m_bEditFocus(true)
{
    setPlaceholderText("please input find word");

m_stringListmodel = new QStringListModel(this);
m_pFindWnd = new QListView(this);
//m_pFindWnd->setWindowFlags(Qt::Popup);
m_pFindWnd->setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::NoEditTriggers);
m_pFindWnd->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
m_pFindWnd->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows);
m_pFindWnd->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::SingleSelection);
m_pFindWnd->setParent(0, Qt::Popup);
m_pFindWnd->setFocusPolicy(Qt::NoFocus);
m_pFindWnd->setFocusProxy(this);

connect(this, SIGNAL(textEdited(const QString&)), this, SLOT(textEditedSlot(const QString&)));
QObject::connect(m_pFindWnd, SIGNAL(clicked(QModelIndex)),
    this, SLOT(clickedSlot(QModelIndex)));
QObject::connect(this, SIGNAL(activated(QModelIndex)),
    m_pFindWnd, SLOT(hide()));

this->installEventFilter(this);
m_pFindWnd->installEventFilter(this);

}

QFindEdit::~QFindEdit()
{
    delete m_pFindWnd;
}

QStringList& QFindEdit::stringList()
{
    return m_stringList;
}

void QFindEdit::showFindWnd(const QString& text)
{
QStringList sl;  
foreach(QString word, m_stringList) {  
    if (word.contains(text)) {  
        sl << word; 
    }  
}

if (sl.size() == 0) 
{
    hideFineWnd();
    return;
}
m_stringListmodel->setStringList(sl);  
m_pFindWnd->setModel(m_stringListmodel);  

m_pFindWnd->resize(rect().width(), 200);
QPoint pTopleft = mapToGlobal(rect().bottomLeft());
m_pFindWnd->move(pTopleft.x(), pTopleft.y());
m_pFindWnd->show();
}

void QFindEdit::textEditedSlot(const QString& text)
{
    QString strText = text.trimmed();
    if (!strText.isEmpty())
    {
        showFindWnd(strText);
    }
    else
    {
        hideFineWnd();
    }
}

void QFindEdit::clickedSlot(QModelIndex modelIndex)
{
    setText(m_pFindWnd->model()->data(modelIndex).toString());
    hideFineWnd();
}

void QFindEdit::hideFineWnd()
{
    m_pFindWnd->hide();
}

bool QFindEdit::eventFilter(QObject *o, QEvent *e)
{
if (m_bEditFocus && (o == this) && e->type() == QEvent::FocusOut) 
{
    if (m_pFindWnd && m_pFindWnd->isVisible())
        return true;
}

if (o != m_pFindWnd)
    return __super::eventFilter(o, e);

switch (e->type()) 
{
case QEvent::KeyPress: 
    {
        QKeyEvent *ke = static_cast<QKeyEvent *>(e);
        QModelIndex curIndex = m_pFindWnd->currentIndex();
        QModelIndexList selList = m_pFindWnd->selectionModel()->selectedIndexes();
        const int key = ke->key();

        if ((key == Qt::Key_Up || key == Qt::Key_Down) && selList.isEmpty() && curIndex.isValid() )
        {
            m_pFindWnd->setCurrentIndex(curIndex);
            return true;
        }

        switch (key) 
        {
        case Qt::Key_End:
        case Qt::Key_Home:
            if (ke->modifiers() & Qt::ControlModifier)
                return false;
            break;

        case Qt::Key_Up:
            if (!curIndex.isValid()) 
            {
                int rowCount = m_pFindWnd->model()->rowCount();
                QModelIndex lastIndex = m_pFindWnd->model()->index(rowCount - 1, m_pFindWnd->modelColumn());
                m_pFindWnd->setCurrentIndex(lastIndex);
                return true;
            } 
            else if (curIndex.row() == 0) 
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;

        case Qt::Key_Down:
            if (!curIndex.isValid()) 
            {
                QModelIndex firstIndex = m_pFindWnd->model()->index(0, m_pFindWnd->modelColumn());
                m_pFindWnd->setCurrentIndex(firstIndex);
                return true;
            } 
            else if (curIndex.row() == m_pFindWnd->model()->rowCount() - 1) 
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        m_bEditFocus = false;
        this->event(ke);
        m_bEditFocus = true;
        if ( e->isAccepted() || !m_pFindWnd->isVisible()) {
            if (!this->hasFocus())
                hideFineWnd();
            if (e->isAccepted())
                return true;
        }

        switch (key) 
        {
        case Qt::Key_Return:
        case Qt::Key_Enter:
        case Qt::Key_Tab:
            hideFineWnd(); 
            if (curIndex.isValid()) 
            {  
                QString text = m_pFindWnd->currentIndex().data().toString();  
                setText(text);  
            }  
            break;

        case Qt::Key_F4:
            if (ke->modifiers() & Qt::AltModifier)
                hideFineWnd();
            break;

        case Qt::Key_Backtab:
        case Qt::Key_Escape:
            hideFineWnd();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        return true;
    }
case QEvent::MouseButtonPress: 
    if (!m_pFindWnd->underMouse()) 
    {
        hideFineWnd();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
case QEvent::InputMethod:
case QEvent::ShortcutOverride:
    QApplication::sendEvent(this, e);
    break;

default:
    return false;
}
return false;
}
```