# Keyboard input stops working in Qt 4.4 program when window pops up

Tags: qt, keyboard

I'm having a problem with a Qt 4.4 program which stops being able to receive keyboard input at random times when a popup window is displayed. Most of the time it works fine, but occasionally it will stop receiving keyboard input after one of two popup windows is displayed. The one is a simple window with a text edit and ok/cancel buttons. The other is a custom dialog with a date/time selector.

I'm currently running RHEL 5.6 with Qt 4.4. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7654422/no-keyboard-input-if-qlineedit-on-frameless-popup-window) seems to describe a similar type of problem, but this only happens sporadically, so does anyone have any ideas?

edit: One of the windows is modal and one is not. The edit box definitely has focus and after dismissing the window/popup, none of the edit boxes in the rest of the program will accept keyboard input.

Comment: Are you sure it's a keyboard issue, not just missing focus?

Comment: It shows the cursor slowly blinking like normal and the text edit widget definitely has focus.

Answer (score 2):

If the popup windows are modal then the keyboard input won't propagate to the other windows:

> A modal dialog is a dialog that blocks input to other visible windows
>   in the same application.

For more information check [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qdialog.html#modal-dialogs)

Comment: The window is modal, but I'm talking about the keyboard input into the modal modal itself.

Comment: You should provide some more code... If you click on the line edit of the dialog you still don't catch keyboard events?

Comment: Ya, I can click on the text edit and the little blinking cursor is visible and it definitely has focus, but still no keyboard input. I'll see if I can make a stripped down example that exhibits the same behavior.